# nginx does not execute the index.php file in http://localhost root and just downloads the index.php file

Tags: macos, nginx, localhost, virtualhost

nginx does not execute an index.php file in the `http://localhost` root. I also changed the `default_type  application/octet-stream;` to `default_type  application/html;` but no luck. Below is the `nginx.conf` file:

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
error_log /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/error.log;
pid       /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include       /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log    /usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        access_log  /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/logs/localhost.access.log  combined;

        location / {
            root   /Users/apiah/Websites/test;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            include        /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here is the information from `nginx -V` command in terminal:

`TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-ipv6 --sbin-path=/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/bin/nginx --with-cc-opt='-I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.34/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f/include' --with-ld-opt='-L/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.34/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1f/lib' --conf-path=/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/usr/local/var/run/nginx/scgi_temp --http-log-path=/usr/local/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log --with-http_gzip_static_module`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `root` directive inside location is perfectly valid, but there are few cases when it's appropriate and this one is definitely not the case. Read [common pitfalls](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block).

Second, relative root path (`root html;` in your case) is relative to nginx default path. Do you know what it is? Yes, it's `/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6` as stated in your post. So `root html;` equivalent `root /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.4.6/html;`. I guess, there is no PHP file.

Third, nginx does not execute anything. In this case nginx proxies your request to fastcgi application on port 9000 (I guest, it's php-fpm or something like this).

Also, there are lot of useful messages in error log. Try to look into it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. you are right, I changed the `root html;` to `root /Users/apiah/Websites/test;` and added `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /Users/apiah/Websites/test$fastcgi_script_name;` and everything works fine now.
`